# Trouble about goroutine concurrent

Tags: go

I got some trouble about goroutine concurrent. In my expect, it should run asynchronously and print out almost at same time but what it really did was running with waiting

#### MyTestCode

```
package main

type batchD []string
var cBD = make(chan batchD, 6)

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())

    data := [][]string{}
    data = append(data, []string{"71", "40348270", "6", "win888e", "6", "1", "N", "127.0.0.1"})
    data = append(data, []string{"71", "40348270", "6", "win888e", "6", "1", "N", "127.0.0.1"})
    data = append(data, []string{"71", "40348270", "6", "win888e", "6", "1", "N", "127.0.0.1"})
    data = append(data, []string{"71", "129499244", "6", "win888e", "6", "1", "N", "127.0.0.1"})
    data = append(data, []string{"71", "40348270", "6", "win888e", "6", "1", "N", "127.0.0.1"})
    data = append(data, []string{"71", "40348270", "6", "win888e", "6", "1", "N", "127.0.0.1"})

    for k,v := range data {
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(k,v)
            //batchD{}.BatchDeposit(v[0],v[1],v[2],v[3],v[4],v[5],v[6],v[7])
            delay()
            cBD <- data[k]
        }()
        <-cBD
    }
}

func delay() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    t := Basic.NowTime("Taipei")
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

#### Output I got

```
0 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
1 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:41  
2 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:42  
3 [71 129499244 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:43  
4 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:44  
5 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:45
```

#### Output I Expected

```
0 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
1 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
2 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
3 [71 129499244 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
4 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
5 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40
```

Any suggestions or tips will helps. Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between expected and real output here? BTW, if the go routines are not synchronized their print output may get jumbled.

Comment: I had edit my output statement. I knew no synchronized output will jumbled but is accepted if it look like this.   
  
0 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
4 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40  
1 [71 40348270 6 win888e 6 1 N 127.0.0.1]  
2017-08-16 12:00:40

Comment: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Comment: If you are hoping that all the gouroutines will run at (and hence, output) the same time, you need to read [concurrency is not parallelism](https://blog.golang.org/concurrency-is-not-parallelism)

Comment: @Weiwei one more problem I see is that more than one go routine may end  up reading same value of k and v. To avoid that, you should pass k and v as parameters to the groutine function.

Comment: Note that `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` is unnecessary in modern versions of Go, as that is already the default.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you have:

```
var cBD = make(chan batchD, 6)
for k := range data {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println(time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
        cBD <- data[k]
    }()
    <-cBD
}
```

Each loop starts a goroutine. The loop then waits, via the channel receive `<-cBD`, until the goroutine sends to the channel, via `cBD <- data[k]`, one second later. For example,

```
2017-08-16 02:52:46
2017-08-16 02:52:47
2017-08-16 02:52:48
2017-08-16 02:52:49
2017-08-16 02:52:50
2017-08-16 02:52:51
```

Comment: He used a non-blocking buffered channel.

Comment: @ivan.sim It doesn't matter if it's buffered. The channel is empty when he's trying to read from it, so the execution waits until something is sent to the channel.

Comment: @lmazgon yes, you are right. The receiver will remain blocked.

Comment: Yeah, this answer hits the nail on the head. Not sure why asker expected any different behavior - it appears to be written deliberately to behave as it does.